# How to build a website for the tensorflow flower example?

Tags: php, docker, tensorflow

https://petewarden.com/2016/02/28/tensorflow-for-poets/
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#docker-installation

I follow above links to install tensorflow flower example on 
my ubuntu 14.04.  Inside docker, compiling, learning, and 
classifying commands all seem to be working, luckily.

docker version:1,11,2  bazel version:0.3.0 images: /home/tf_files
docker image:  gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-gpu

Next step is to set up a website to have people upload the 
image for testing.  I use LAMP (/var/www/html, outside docker). 
The problem is that PHP (shell_exec) and inside-docker commands 
are not talking. How to solve this? Any input is welcome.

Comment: can you give some more specific examples of what you are trying to do and what the errors are?

Comment: Take inside-docker compiling command for example:
root@63a6491c2514:/tensorflow# bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain
it is working.  However, outside docker,  shell_exec(‘bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain’) won’t work. The basic idea is that when a image is uploaded through the browser, php would perform the inside-docker command and show the results on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the benefits of containerization is to provide isolation to protect from things like you are trying to do. You would need to either install PHP in the same container as your `bazel` app or find some way to pass data back-and-forth. In theory, you could find some way to send or otherwise make the uploaded image available (I'm not familiar with the specifics - i.e., can it access an image via a network protocol?).

And your exec command would look something like:

shell_exec(`docker exec {bazel-container} bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain`);

Where {bazel-container} is a network address for that container. Using a script on the bazel container would make that command easier. And putting your PHP app in a container would make networking easier.

If you could get that all to work, it may do what you need for experimenting, but ultimately you would want to build a more robust interface on the bazel container that ideally would work via HTTP (e.g., a RESTful API) or similar.

Comment: Thank for the great guiding! It will take quite some time to work out all the details. A few responses: (1)Uploaded image : As long as it is saved inside /home/tf_files, the classifying command will have no problem to find it. (2) PHP container: Our LAMP server has been there for sometimes. It may be easier to deal with bazel container I/O rather than to move the whole LAMP server for now. (3) Web front-end : In Link 1, an android solution has been suggested. We feel that web front-end is as important.

Comment: For the image saving then, you could make `/home/tf_files` a shared volume.

Comment: To activate docker,  we use  $docker run -it -v /home/tf_files:/tf_files gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-gpu    I guess it is a shared volume. What is best way to send text results from bazel container out to the PHP? Through shared volume?

Comment: Curl or similar probably since it's a server and can accept requests.

Comment: Allow me to be more specific. To run a classifier
root@c8f3cf27ad14:/tensorflow# bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image && \
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image \
--graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
--output_layer=final_result \
--image=/tf_files/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg

On the terminal, it reads at the end of many lines

Comment: I tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:207] daisy (4): 0.997547
I tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:207] sunflowers (3): 0.00152006
I tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:207] dandelion (2): 0.000578198
I tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:207] tulips (0): 0.000194673
I tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:207] roses (1): 0.000160431

I like to return this to PHP and show on the browser.